# Is there a way to export a Mercurial repo from Bitbucket to Azure DevOps, including the issue tracker?

Tags: git, azure-devops, mercurial, bitbucket

I have some repos I'd like to migrate - converting them from hg to git shouldn't be too much of a problem, but the issue tracker is paramount to me as I have lots of issues I don't want to lose! Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Migrating the repositories should be fairly straight-forward.
[Microsoft Repository Import Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops)

I'm not 100% sure about the issue tracker though.  I've heard you can use [OPS Hub](https://www.opshub.com/).  But I haven't personally used it.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you first go through the tutorial-- [Import a Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops). This guide shows you how to import an existing Git repo from GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab, or other location into a new or empty existing repo in your Azure DevOps.

There are also many tutorials in google, you could take a look at [this one](https://blog.verslu.is/tools/moving-git-repo-bitbucket-vsts/) which show the detail steps both in Azure DevOps and BitBucket side.

As for the issue tracker part, there isn't any built-in tool or simple way to migrate the BitBucket issues to Azure DevOps. As we can see the issues in BitBucket and the **work items** in Azure DevOps are **using** totally **different templates**. If you have large amount of issues need to be migrated, you may create an application and use Azure DevOps Rest API and BitBucket API to do this.

You can also try exporting the issues to Excel  from BitBucket, then edit the Excel file to match the format in Azure DevOps (mapping the fields) and import to Azure DevOps finally. Please see [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) for details.